# Excel VBA If then statements

Tags: vba, excel

i want to if my cell (b5,c5) is blank than cell (f5,g5,h5) also make blank also ,cell (b6,c6) is blank than cell (f6,g6,h6) ,cell (b7,c7) is blank than cell (f7,g7,h7) ,cell (b8,c8) is blank than cell (f8,g8,h8) ,cell (b9,c9) is blank than cell (f9,g9,h9) ,  but same in i want this code 200 time help me make a small code.thanks in advance.

```
Sub BLANK()

    If Range("B5,C5") = "" Then
    Range("F5,G5,H5") = ""
    If Range("B6,C6") = "" Then
    Range("F6,G6,H6") = ""
    If Range("B7,C7") = "" Then
    Range("F7,G7,H7") = ""
    ' same code in cell("b5:b200") make small code please
     end if
  end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will loop over 200 times and produce the results you require

```
For x = 5 to 200
   If Range(Cells(x,2), Cells(x,3)).Value = "" Then
      Range(Cells(x,6), Cells(x,8)).Value = ""
   End if
Next x
```

Comment: SORRY IT NOT WORK SOME ERROR

Answer (score 1):

I will recomend you to use something like this. Where ranges and sheet is properly declared, and also all variables are properly declared with using `option explicit` to prevent you from multiple issues

```
Sub makeBlank()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = Sheets("devSheet")

Dim rowCounter As Long

With mySheet
    For rowCounter = 5 To 200
        If .Range("B" & rowCounter & ",C" & rowCounter).Value = "" Then
            .Range("F" & rowCounter & ",G" & rowCounter & ",H" & rowCounter).Value = ""
        End If
    Next rowCounter
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU IT IS WORK VERY WELL THANKS

Comment: @RameshVerma in stack overflow thanks for working solution is added by accepting answer or/and voting up the answer...